# onbeforeunload with window.open is not working

Tags: javascript

**YES I KNOW THIS IS A DUPLICATE, BUT THE OTHER ONE WAS TOO CONFUSING TO ME.**

So, as in the title, I can't make onbeforeunload with window.open to work. this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>NOPE!</title></head>
    <body onbeforeunload="window.open('#')">
        <h1>Can't close me!</h1>
    </body>e
</html>
```

This would really help. If you want the thing that I am working on it for this, cantclosethis.playcode.io

Basically, my goal is so the user cannot close the tab without restarting chrome.

Edit: I would've commented on the first one, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Not possible. Can only use `window.open()` in user initiated event like click.

Comment: Thanks to abuse from people, you can not do things like this. I miss the late 90s early 2000s when you could open up a browser with no close button, no resize button. Of the joys.

Comment: That kinda makes sense... I'll keep this up just to let others know that it is, unfortunately, impossible.